# Word to describe killing for deterrence

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or phrase that describes an event where someone or a group of people are killed or executed, usually publicly, as a means of deterrence?

A close candidate is a "scare tactic."

Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a single word, but when a person is or group of people are killed to show what happens to people who act thus, it can be said that they were "made an example of."

> [***make an example of somebody***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+an+example+of)
>
> to punish someone for doing something so that other people will not do the same thing. *They want to make an example of him by keeping him in prison under very difficult conditions.*

Answer (score 3):

There is the phrase ***pour encourager les autres,*** literally "to encourage the others". Although it's French, it's been borrowed.

Wikipedia has a quote from Voltaire about Admiral Byng. Byng was a British naval commander who lost the island of Minorca to the French in 1756. He was court-martialled and executed.

> Byng's execution is referred to in Voltaire's novel *Candide* with the line *Dans ce pays-ci, il est bon de tuer de temps en temps un amiral pour encourager les autres* – "In this country, it is wise to kill an admiral from time to time to encourage the others."

A similar tactic was employed by decimation of legions in Ancient Rome (every tenth soldier was extracted from a parade and executed); and to a certain extent by Nazi reprisal executions during the Second World War.

Answer (score 0):

*[Intimidation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intimidation#Noun)*, meaning "The act of making timid or fearful or of deterring by threats", somewhat applies; only somewhat because threats often are not as extreme as killings.  *[Requital](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/requital)* ("Compensation for loss or damage; amends.
Retaliation or reprisal; vengeance") and related words (*[revenge](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/revenge)*, *[retribution](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retribution)*, *[reprisal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reprisal)*, *[retaliation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retaliation)*) may not apply in that the question's "means of deterrence" phrase somewhat implies a [preemptive strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemptive_strike) rather than requital.

Answer (score -2):

The term ***decimate*** was originally used to describe a practice of taking one out of ten of a defeated group and killing them.  This is derived from the word *decimus* meaning *tenth*.

The practice served to show the power of the victor and to deter further resistance by the conquered.

It is often used now (I think not very well) to indicate a drastic reduction without regard to the word's root in the term for *tenth*.

Comment: Your statement is correct, but I don't think it answers the OP's question about making an example about someone.

Comment: No the statements are incorrect. The Romans [decimated their own forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_%28Roman_army%29), not opposing armies as implied here. And decimate nowadays *does* have regard to the etymology: these days it's a tenth which is left (having removed the other nine tenths). And it doesn't answer the question, I'm afraid: *decimate* does not mean to make an example, or intimidate others into compliance.

Comment: @Andrew Leach - my recollection from first year Latin of 50+ years ago is extremely weak, and I think AL is right as to who was killed.  However, I think the purpose, is exactly as OP asked - executing one tenth of the soldiers who rebelled or failed to fight well, *publicly as a means of deterrence*.